# Larvelでpost処理時の画面遷移

Tags: laravel

Laravelでpost処理し、画面遷移したいですが、出来ません。
エラー内容は下記です。

> The requested URL /hello was not found on this server.

コード以外の設定の部分もあるかと思いますが、調べても原因がわかりません。
ご教授よろしくお願いいたします。

**index.blade.php**

```php
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello/Index</title>
    <style>
        body{font-size:16pt; color:#999;}
        h1{font-size:50pt; text-align:right; color:#f6f6f6;
         margin:20px 0px -30px 0px; letter-spacing:-4pt;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Blade/Index</h1>
    <p>{{$msg}}</p>
    <form method="POST" action="/hello">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <input type="text" name="msg">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**HelloController.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

class HelloController extends Controller
{
    //Action記述
    public function index(){

        $data = ['msg'=> '名前を入力してください。',
        ];
        return view('hello.index', $data);
    }

    public function post(Request $request){
        $msg = $request->msg;
        $data=['msg'=>'こんにちは'.$msg.'さん',];
        return view('hello.index',$data);
    }

}
```

**web.php**

```php
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('hello', 'HelloController@index');
Route::post('hello', 'HelloController@post');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Route::get('hello', 'HelloController@index');
Route::post('hello', 'HelloController@post');
```

を以下の様に修正したらできませんか？

```
Route::get('/hello', 'HelloController@index');
Route::post('/hello', 'HelloController@post');
```

Comment: ご返信遅くなりすいません。
教えていただいた様に修正しましたが、エラー内容は同じでした。
formのactionが”/hello”となっていたので、"/"を外して元のコードで実行すると遷移出来ました。
ご回答がヒントになりました。

ありがとうございました！！！

Comment: 解決して何よりです